# Regex URL validation for angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create validation for URL which will accept the following cases
with HTTP or https or without, with www or without, with subpages or without

```
http://website.com
https://website.com
http://website.com/
http://www.website.com
website.com
http://website.com/page/id/sdf
```

I tried the following, but it did not cover all cases above

```
$scope.urlPattern = '^(([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*[?].*)?$'
$scope.urlPattern = '^((https?|ftp)://)?([a-z]+[.])?[a-z0-9-]+([.][a-z]{1,4}){1,2}(/.*[?].*)?$'
```

> I do not have permission to add a comment, So I am editing for my answer only. Below link has all type of URL validation, hope it will help you:

[All type URL validation link](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex)

Comment: consider the `m`-flag for multiline search

Comment: or you can use the ultimate https://gist.github.com/dperini/729294

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to validate the url, you don't really need to concern the 'www' condition (since it is included in other condition)

Something simple can be done like this:

`'^(https?:\/\/)*[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)+(\/[a-z0-9-]+)*\/?$'`

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/q0d69jq3/2/

Answer (score 0):

var result = url.match(/(http(s)?://.)?(www.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%.*+~#=]{2,256}.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%*+.~#?&//=]*)/g);

```
    if (result == null) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        return true;
                    };
```